# Холодное или холодец?

Tags: лексика

Я с детства слышал название блюда "холодное", а потом уже узнал, что оно называется "холодец". А название "холодное" равноправно или это уже какой-то диалект?

Comment: Студень из говяжьих продуктов, холодец из свиных. Это вся разница) и, как итог, и то и это "холодное".

Comment: @СергейМусенко А из медвежатины? )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Холодное - это общее название для всех холодных закусок, холодец - вид закуски. В качестве синонимов я их не слышала, в толковом словаре не видела (может, в каком и есть...), а вот в словаре синонимов к слову "холодное" дается синоним "холодец".

Answer (score 0):

Насчет словарей. если не синоним, но гипероним уж точно, как и было сказано.

ХОЛОДНОЕ, -ого; ср.
Блюдо, подаваемое для еды в охлаждённом виде; холодная закуска. Подать на стол х.
(БТС).

Если я правилно понимаю точку с запятой, "холодное" - даже и не закуска, вернее не только закуска, а вообще всякое неподогретое пере подачей на стол блюдо. От окрошки до компота.

Признаюсь, не слышал, чтобы компот величали "холодным", а вот свекольник или там зеленые щи - это именно то значение, котрое и я до сих пор пользую. В отношении закусок - это для меня даже в некотором роде новость. Холодец же - синоним студня. Хотя знатоки, наверное, знают различия и между ними, но это уж я опускаю.

С остальным - согласен.